# Symfony2 : How to get a default value from a form in Controller?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I want to get a default value from a form. For example, I rendered a select box form by using the following code:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('patient', 'choice', array(
                'choices' => $patientArray,
                'required' => true,
                'label' => false
            ))
            ->getForm();
```

The `patientArray` values are composed of `patient_id` and `patient_name` :

```
array(
    '2' => 'John'
    '3' => 'Jane'
);
```

So, I would like to get the default value which is `2 => John` without submit a button and without choosing the select form. What is a proper way to achieve this in a controller?

Comment: Not sure if this would work but you could use `'data' => current(array_keys($patientArray))` to set the empty data and then use `$form->get('patient')->getEmptyData()` or possible `$form->get('patient')->getData()`. Again, not sure if that would actually work though.

Comment: @Qoop Thanks for your response. It's quite a good idea! I still wonder that how can I get the form object in another action method, `indexAction`?

Comment: You could create your form as a service and then just call it like any other service with `$this->createForm('my.form')`. - See http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#defining-your-forms-as-services

Answer (score -2):

You need to set default value in your `entity`. You can use `__construct()` method for it.

```
    // create a task and give it some dummy data for this example
    $task = new Task();
    $task->setTask('Write a blog post');
    $task->setDueDate(new \DateTime('tomorrow'));

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
        ->add('task', 'text')
        ->add('dueDate', 'date')
        ->add('save', 'submit')
        ->getForm();

    return $this->render('AcmeTaskBundle:Default:new.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
```

In this example `task` field has `Write a blog post` value by default. You also can do this in `__construct()`, and you don't need use setter, but it is't necessary.

But better use `__construct` instead `setter` like:

```
// src/Acme/TaskBundle/Entity/Task.php
namespace Acme\TaskBundle\Entity;

class Task
{
    protected $task;

    protected $dueDate;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->task = 'Write a blog post';
    }
```

and you always have default value when create `Task` object

P.s. You can find more examples in [forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html) documentation

Comment: Could you give some examples?

Comment: Thanks for your immediately response. The question is actually how can I get the default value from a `Select box`, for example, I have `patientFormAction` used to render a form. Then, when I open the first page of my application, the `indexAction` will be executed, so,  I want to get the first value of the `select box` form, `2 => John`, in order to use it in my `indexAction`.

Comment: So you want to get default value of form field (that you create in `patientFormAction` action), in the other action `indexAction`, right?

Comment: Exactly Victor. I am thinking about using `Session`. However, I don't know if it's a good idea.

Comment: Yes. Better to use `__construct` method in entity. I add example of entity with `construct` method